# Offline Geo calculations using Ruby, can they be done?

Tags: ruby, database, geolocation

I'm new to GeoCoding/GeoData/etc, and have a question about making calculations without connecting to an online Geo service.

If already know the longitude and latitude for `x`, and the longitude and latitude for `y`, is it possible to determine the distance between the two points without accessing an online service (ie Google, Geocoder.ca, etc)?

Currently the data is in a MySQL database.

Note: I have found a couple of semi-related answers here, but they link to C libraries, while I'm using Ruby.

**UPDATE:** Just in case you are already using RubyGeocoder for online service enquiries, you may be interested to know that it has the Haversine function built-in, [documented here](http://rdoc.info/github/alexreisner/geocoder/master/Geocoder/Calculations#distance_between-instance_method).

Comment: Anything that doesn't involve something like Google's location database can probably be done with the right algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distance between to points can be calculated using the **Haversine formula**. (Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)

Here is an example implementation:
http://www.esawdust.com/blog/gps/files/HaversineFormulaInRuby.html

Answer (score 0):

Since our Earth is an ellipsoid instead of a sphere, If you are looking for a more accurate solution, take a look at [Lambert's formula](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24531873).

I've made an implementation for this.

https://github.com/tonytonyjan/geodesics

It Passes a test set of 500,000 geodesics for the WGS84 ellipsoid with more than **99%** accuracy.